# Passing a comma delimited string into a class

Tags: java, string, class, parsing

Here is what I have so far in my code

```
public class Person {

public Person()
{
   String person = "";
   int age = 0;
   String city = "";
   int sibCount = 0;

 // make an  instance field for name, city, age, and siblingCount       
   Person person = new Person();
   Person age = new Person();
   Person city = new Person();
   Person sibCount = new Person();  

}
// make a method called parseCommaDelim
public void parseCommaDelim(String[] args){
    // return a Person instance UNSURE HERE

   }
    // make a toString method
   public String toString()
   {
       String str = "person" + person + "age" + age + "city" + city;
       return str;
   }

}
}
```

I am trying return a person instance and I am not sure how to do it. I tried 'return Person;' and my code did not like it.

My toString method is not working either because it does not know what person, age, or city is, and I am not sure why.

Comment: You should learn java basics first because it seems you don't have a clue about how Objects work in java.

Comment: Not sure if its a typo but you should do   `String city = "";` not `String City = "";`

Comment: Your method return type is void. SO it can't return anything. Also, your person constructor calls you person constructor, which calls your person constructor, which calls your person constructor... I suggest you re-read your book or tutorial about methods and constructors.

Comment: The first thing to learn is Java standard naming conventions, which dictates all types begin with a capital letter and capitalize each word thereafter. For example `ClassName`  Variable names start with a lowercase letter and capitalize all words thereafter, for example `variableName`.  Following these guidelines will prevent you from having a variable name which is the same as the class type, hence `String Person = "";`

Comment: Please learn [the basics of OO programming first](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/). We would have to write an entire book to get this code on the right path and why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Here is a video on how to create a class in java: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2AJQhaUVLI. Read up on the other links users have posted as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is probably something along the following lines:

```
public class Person {

  // fields
  private String person = "";
  private int age = 0;
  private String city = "";
  private int sibCount = 0;

  // constructor
  public Person() {
  }

  // public access methods (getters)
  public String getPerson() {
    return this.person;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
  }

  public String getCity() {
    return this.city;
  }

  public int getSibCount() {
    return this.sibCount;
  }

  // toString
  public String toString() {
    return "person: " + person + ", age: " + age + ", city: " + city;

  // factory method
  public static Person parseCommaDelim(String s) {
    String[] tokens = s.split(",");

    Person instance = new Person();
    instance.person = tokens[0];
    instance.age = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1];
    instance.city = tokens[2];
    // ...

    return instance;
  }
}
```

The field `person` should probably renamed to `name`. Depending wether you want to make your class immutable or not you may want to add either a constructor which takes all parameters as parameters:

```
public Person(String name, int age, String city, int sibCount) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.city = city;
  this.sibCount = sibCount;
}
```

or add setters for the changable fields, for example:

```
public void setCity(String city) {
  this.city = city;
}
```

btw. with above constructor you could modify the factory to the following slightly cleaner code:

```
  public static Person parseCommaDelim(String s) {
    String[] tokens = s.split(",");

    String person = tokens[0];
    int age = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1];
    String city = tokens[2];
    int sibCount = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);

    return new Person(person, age, city, sibCount);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person {

   public String person;
   public int age;
   public String city;
   public int sibCount;  

public Person()
{
   person = "";
   age = 0;
   city = "";
   sibCount = 0;

}
// make a method called parseCommaDelim
public String parseCommaDelim(String[] args){
    // return a Person instance UNSURE HERE

   }
    // make a toString method
   public String toString()
   {
       String str = "person" + person + "age" + age + "city" + city;
       return str;
   }


}
```

Comment: The fields of person should not be exposed with the public modifier.  There is also an extra closing brace.

Comment: Thank you that made my class work. Do you have any tips on returning the person instance from the parse method?